# Forcing length of txt box or variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, msgbox

I have some javascript code. I want to put in some error checking but don't know where to start.
I want, if the contents of val1 is not exactly 21 characters in length, to stop the script, or better still give a message box to the fact.
Or maybe it is possible to force the input box to containing 21 characters?
Sorry if its a silly question but I am new to this and still learning.

I set the size of the input box to 21 but this only increase the dimension so its still possible to enter more or less characters than this.
I thought maybe some sort of *if* statement might do it but dont know how to do this and my attempts have been unsuccessful.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

    // Get base64URL
    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
    var val1 = $('#datepicker').val();

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       //data: {image: base64URL, name: datepicker},
       data: {image: base64URL, datepicker: val1},
       success: function(data){
       console.log('Upload successfully');
       }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

No matter what I tried it stopped the script working altogether, even when val1 was 21 characters.

This is what I tried after being given some additional code (thanks). But unfortunately it does not work for me (no message and script does not save image to server).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

    // Get base64URL
    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
    var val1 = $('#datepicker').val();
    var val1_length = val1.length;    

    if(val1_length != 21)
        {
            alert("please enter 21 character ....");
        }
    else
    {

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       //data: {image: base64URL, name: datepicker},
       data: {image: base64URL, datepicker: val1},
       success: function(data){
       console.log('Upload successfully');
       }
    });
  });
}
}
</script>
```

I have resolved this.
In the end I decided to use a function inside JavaScript, outside of the ajax code.
It is a much more elegant solution, imo, and will ensure the users will know what data needs to be entered (and to use the date picker calendar).

```
function ValidateDate()
{
var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker');
var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
var FullDate = 21;   

  if (datepicker.length !== FullDate) {
  {
    alert("The Date Must Have a Start *and* End Date. Use the Calendar to Ensure this. Do Not enter any other text in the Box!");
    document.getElementById("datepicker").focus();
    return false;
  }
  } else {
    screenshot();      
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check then, in devtools, if the post request is being sent at all and if so, what's the response, it may be BE related issue. Also, try debugging/ console.log to check the value of `val1_lenght`

Comment: You have lost me there. BE related?

Comment: By BE (backend) related I mean that if ajax call to ,`axajfile.php` is made and you don't see the expected result in DB then it's something wrong with how you process the data you send

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Don't think its that. It worked flawlessly until I tried to add the code to test string length. I will do some experimenting later.

Comment: I have looked at the devtools and the post is not getting sent. The error is always: ReferenceError: val1_length is not defined. This happens if I start the if statement after html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) { ( ut here it executes the canvas code first. Or if I put it after function screenshot(){ it stops dead without executing any code.

Comment: And what would be the value of `val1`?

Comment: its from a datepicker app I installed. It is a text field of 21 characters. its in the format 2019-07-14_2019-07-21 but I just realised it has .jpg appended to it so it is 25 characters in total.

Comment: I just changed your if statement so it is not for 25 characters and added it back to my code. I am not getting any error about val1 now but it allows upload even if it is less than 25 characters. I will update original post with the code so you could please check i have added it correctly as it is probably my fault.

Comment: it looks perfectly fine now. Try attaching breakpoint and debug the value of `val1` variable: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: I just had a thought. Might it be better to do the if statement where the button is clicked? Maybe in a new function and if the check is ok it then calls the screenshot function? I will investigate this.

Comment: for something that simple it doesn't really matter if you move your check it another function or not, in fact that would be a bit of overkill

Comment: OK, I was wrong. it is 21 characters. the .jpg gets added in the php later, before the contents are put/posted on the server. OK I have finally figured out the debugger. Just looking at a breakpoint now.

Comment: 1st test the var1 value was "2019-08-25_2019-08-31". this got posted as 2019-08-25_2019-08-31.jpg  -  2nd test the var1 value was "2019-08-18_..." this got posted as 2019-08-18_....jpg

Comment: I have uploaded a test server. Would really appreciate it if you could take a look at some point. To pick a date you choose any sunday and then the following saturday. Cheers :) http://flakie.epizy.com/index.html

Comment: everything seems to be working as expected when using debugger, and, being honest, I think I've already helped you out a lot ;)

Comment: No worries and cheers. I will find a different way to do the checking.

Comment: I have resolved this now. I decided it was best to use a new JavaScript function outside of ajax. It works well. I have updated me original question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. In the end I decided to use a function inside JavaScript, outside of the ajax code. It is a much more elegant solution, imo, and will ensure the users will know what data needs to be entered (and to use the date picker calendar).

```
function ValidateDate()
{
var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
var FullDate = 21;   

  if (datepicker.length !== FullDate) {
  {
    alert("The Date Must Have a Start *and* End Date. Use the Calendar to Ensure this. Do Not enter any other text in the Box!");
    document.getElementById("datepicker").focus();
    return false;
  }
  } else {
    screenshot();      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

What you're missing is a simple check of value of `val1`, so the script is executed fully. That's what you're looking for in JS:

```
var val1 = $('#datepicker').val();

if (val1.length !== 21) {
  // AJAX request
  $.ajax({
   url: 'ajaxfile.php',
   type: 'post',
   //data: {image: base64URL, name: datepicker},
   data: {image: base64URL, datepicker: val1},
   success: function(data){
   console.log('Upload successfully');
   }
})}
```

Another way is, if `#datepicker` input is of type `text` you can set `maxlength` attribute on this element, so it would not possible to enter more characters than set.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I set the maxlenght and minlength to 21 but they are still able to put less characters in (but the box does turn red so will keep this in place). So they can still upload image to server with incorrect formatting (too few characters).

Answer (score 0):

it is simple. first find length of val1 variable

```
>> var val1_length = val1.value.length;
```

then using if condition check length is 21 or not

> > 

```
 if(val1_length != 21)
        {
            alert("please enter 21 character ....");
        }
    else
    {
        // Your code if value contain 21 charcter
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh. I tried it and have updated my original post but does not work for me. It is probably my fault, putting something in wrong place.